# How do I resolve this parameter in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload, url-parameters

I am trying to combine Carrierwave and jQuery file uploads. The files are being uploaded, but I am facing an issue with fetching the parameters.

This is how the parameters are passed:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Q6AvptpHm59DMIJy86g9hGCzjhUnP8cwpIHZIntAplvYrj+J5UhifXiLp/bxKitHO9WfjYRPLEhaqIKia3xZkw==", "myfile"=>{"attachment"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd46b3def68 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150117-31080-b37zni.png>, @original_filename="Screen Shot 2015-01-17 at 12.18.19 PM.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myfile[attachment][]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2015-01-17 at 12.18.19 PM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">]}, "myfolder_id"=>"1"}
```

I am trying to fetch these parameters in the controller this way:

```
@myfile = @parentfolder.myfiles.new(attachment: params[:myfile_attributes])
```

Which is clearly wrong. Any help would be appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your log:

```
 Parameters: { ... "myfile"=>{"attachment"=>[....]} ... }
```

and try this:

```
params[:myfile][:attachment]
```

or this (if i right, i see that your attachment in the array):

```
params[:myfile][:attachment].first
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!! You are wonderful :) I'll accept the answer when my timer runs out.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Parameters: { "myfile"=>
 {"attachment"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd46b3def68 @tempfile=# }
}
```

#this is how you can access the attachment parameter! 
  But regarding your upload thing, you need to paste your my_files_params function defination here )

```
try params["myfiles"]["attachment"]
```